# Drag-and-Drop - Limiting duplicate MCs for single use in targets?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5.5

I've been working on a Flash drag-and-drop scene using AS3.  The scene is broken into 4 "zones", and each zone has 5 targets.  I've used arrays to allow the mc's to be dropped in their respective zones, without any particular order.  All of this works as it should.

The issue I have it that there are 2 "puzzle" pieces (MCs) that are identical to one-another in terms of how they visually display on the screen.  I've set up the arrays to allow for both to be dropped in zone 1 or zone 2.  However, I'd like to set it up so that if "identical piece 1" gets dropped into zone 1, then "identical piece 2" cannot also be dropped into that same zone.

Any suggestions for how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

How about setting a flag in every zone that tells if a piece has already been attached to it?

If your zones are MovieClips you can simply add variables to them, and set `mcTarget.isTaken = true` when a piece gets attached to it. If they are simply coordinates, you can use a global array like this

```
private mZoneTaken:Array = new Array();

for (var i:int=0; i<4; i++)
{
   mZoneTaken[i] = new Array();
   for (var j:int = 0; j<5; j++)
   {
      mZoneTaken[i][j] = false;
   }
}
```

Then whenever a piece is dropped on a zone, you can set its flag to `true`, allowing you to prevent any further piece from getting attached to it.

Comment: My zones are movieclips.  However, can you explain how setting a boolean on the targets will keep the duplicate pieces from the same zone?  Even though the duplicate pieces look identical, they have different instance names.

Comment: The idea is that the moment -any- piece gets attached to your zone, the boolean is set to true. Whenever -any- other piece, identical or not, tries to attach itself, the boolean will prevent it. The solution covers a broader spectrum than what you asked, but it has the advantage of taking very little time to implement.

Comment: But that's the problem.  Considering that each zone has 5 puzzle pieces that are supposed to be dropped, I don't want to set a boolean so that only one puzzle piece can get dropped in the zone. Unless I'm missing something in your solution?

Comment: After re-reading your explanation, I think I see where the confusion is. My code already covers your solution.  Once a movieclip gets dropped on to the target movieclip, no other clip can be dropped on that same target.  Because I didn't want the user to have to put the puzzle pieces in a specific order, I set up arrays for the target movieclips for each zone to allow the correct puzzle pieces to be dropped in any specific order.  I have all of this already working. Continued in my second comment...

Comment: Continued...Basically, duplicatepuzzlepiece_1_mc can be dropped onto any of the targets in zone 1 OR zone 2, since it goes in either zone.  To the user, duplicatepuzzlepiece_1_mc looks just like duplicatepuzzlepiece_2_mc (but the user would not know they are different instances).  I would like to be able to somehow limit it to only allowing a user to drop 1 of those duplicates per zone.

Comment: In other words, if duplicatepuzzlepiece_1_mc gets dropped onto any of the 5 targets in zone 1, then duplicatepuzzlepiece_2_mc cannot be dropped into that same zone of 5 targets and can instead only be allowed to be dropped into zone 2 of 5 targets.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would have an array/Vector (Vectors are much, much faster. Though they can be a royal pain to use) of objects within each individual zone. You keep this updated at all times. If you remove one, you use `splice(indexOf(obj),1)` to remove it from the array.

For your problem, I would do this:

```
var p1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var p2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var zoneArray:Array = new Array();//there would be one for each zone, simplified it here

//this code would run whenever an object enters the zone
function zoneEnter(e:Event = null):void{
    var currentZone:Sprite; //set this equal to the zone the sprite just entered
    var currentObject:Sprite = e.currentTarget as Sprite; //this way we know which object just entered currentZone

    if ( currentObject == p1 &&  zoneArray.indexOf(p2) >= 0 ) {
        //prevent it from entering the zone
    }

    if ( currentObject == p2 &&  zoneArray.indexOf(p1) >= 0 ) {
        //prevent it from entering the zone
    }
}
```

There are obviously some limitations here if you are looking at a lot of objects. But if you know, for sure, there will only be two, I think this would be the way to go. If there will be more, you would need to create some kind of control structure that would allow you to check an object against other objects. I could elaborate and give a sample of what I am talking of here if it's needed. It's a tad bit complex, but not hard to implement.

EDIT 10-17-12: Added in example code of how the more advanced logic would look.

```
var puzzleMap:Array = new Array();

var piece1:Piece = new Piece(); //this is the puzzle piece we'll be checking
var piece2:Piece = new Piece(); 
var piece3:Piece = new Piece();
var piece1Objs:Array = [piece2,piece3];
var piece2Objs:Array = [piece1,piece3];

puzzleMap.push({piece:piece1,others:piece1Objs});
puzzleMap.push({piece:piece2,others:puzzle2Objs);

private function stopDragHandler(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    var space:Space = space; //this is the space the object was dropped into (I don't know how you identify them, so this is pseudo code)
    var valid:Boolean = true; //we'll check for a bad drop since it's easiest
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && MovieClip(event.target.dropTarget.parent).allowed.indexOf(event.target) > -1){
        for ( var i:Number = 0; i < puzzleMap.length; i++ ) {
            var current:Object = puzzleMap[i];
            if ( current == e.currentTarget ) {
                for ( var j:Number = 0; j < current.others.length; j++ ) {
                    var checkAgainst:Piece = current.others[i] as Piece;
                    if ( space.currentObjects.indexOf(checkAgainst) < 0 ) {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if ( !valid ) {
            //prevent the drop here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in total, there will be 4 puzzle pieces (2 pairs of duplicates). A sample would be ideal. I'm also curious to know how I would add that function into my existing if statement for stopDrag: "if (event.target.dropTarget != null && MovieClip(event.target.dropTarget.parent).allowed.indexOf(event.target) > -1){ etc....

Comment: @habib_101 I just edited my answer to include the code. It's a bit more advanced than I think you need (my previously posted code or the code provided by Dave Hart will work just fine), but it should do what would be needed. I would highly suggest having different classes for your Pieces and Spaces so that you could nest some of this in there. Ideally, the piece1Objs object and space.currentObjects would be objects/arrays within the class. Again, this is overkill for you. If you were to try to expand your project, though, this might be useful

Comment: I just tried the code by am getting an error 1046 "Type was not found..." on these lines:

var piece1:Piece = new Piece(); //this is the puzzle piece we'll be checking var piece2:Piece = new Piece();  var piece3:Piece = new Piece();

Comment: That code isn't complete. There is a little bit of pseudo code in there because I do not have your project in front of me to fit it in. Piece is a made up class name. As I suggested in my earlier comment, I highly recommend using custom classes here, just so you can add your own properties to them. This was meant to be a guide in terms of the logic behind it more than anything else.